# In postgresql, can we use returning id instead of lastval()?

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql, can we use returning id instead of lastval()?
For example,
Does the statement below ("returning id INTO myid ") runs as lastval() ?
If table2 have multiple rows, Does myid return only last value or multiple values?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.proc1(INOUT myid INTEGER)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
begin 
    insert into public.table1
    select * from public.table2;
    returning id INTO myid ; 
    COMMIT;
    END ;
$$
;
```

Comment: You need to change that into a function that returns a list of IDs. You can return multiple values in a single variable

Comment: If I use insert into public.table1 values(col1,col2)   (not from table2), could i use the proc above?

Comment: You should find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819001/postgres-not-returning-lastval-properly interesting.